# How to get uri of selected file (ACTION_GET_CONTENT) into array ANDROID

Tags: android, arrays, uri

I need help with my Android project. I've got an application where i select file with file browser and then send it by email. Becouse there are other files to send the uri
has to be in array. I need uri of selected file to be added in array which is used in email.intent

Here is code for selecting file :

```
 nalozi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nalozi);
    nalozi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard"); // a directory
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"),REQUEST1);
        }
    }
        )
```

When i select file i am returned back to activity, i need the location (uri) of selected file to be saved into Array

and here is array:

```
 ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            uris.add(Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/camera_app/cam_image.jpg"));
            uris.add(Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/camera_app/prog.jpg"));

            emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);
```

How can I add uri of selected file to this array ?
( to be send with cam_image.jpg an prog.jpg)

I am new to android and java and would really appreciate your help

Thank you

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, in your activity result, use `data.getData();`